# run some script when session end in Yii 1

Tags: php, session, yii

My session configuration in config file (main.php) is:

```
'session' => array(
    'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
    'timeout' => 60*60, // 1 hour
),
```

And I put this code in layout file:

```
<?php if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) { ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo Yii::app()->params['session_timeout'];?>;"/>
<?php } ?>
```

So far, there are no announcement when the session end. When I refresh the browser, the session is already end.

After session (or almost) expired, I want to tell user that the session is going to expire like countdown timer dialog or something.

I have tried this extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/timeout-dialog/. but it didn't work for my website with the configuration. The extension show the dialog when the session is 1 minute left, but when I clicked the button to resume the session, it didn't work because the session still running. I know it  because when I refresh the browser, the session is already expired.

So, what I must do?

At least, I want to know how to get the remaining time of the session when browser refreshed, so I can modified the announcement by myself.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem by myself.

**Here the explanation**:

It's important to be known that Session works on server. When browser accessing to server, session timeout will be restarted. There are no ways to know the remaining time of the session.

So, to warn user that session will expire must be handled in client with javascript or jQuery. I created handlers that will warn user when the website idle (no activities) or when the session timeout is almost expired. User will be warned by a confirmation dialog that asks to user whether would keep sign in or log out. When user decide to keep sign in, client will do ajax to do whatever-script in server (because that will restarted the session timeout).

Because my Yii website using bootstrap 3, So the dialog panel that I create will use bootstrap code.

This is in view layout:

```
<script>
    /* configuration */
    var count = <?php echo Yii::app()->session->getTimeout(); ?>; //session
    var countdown = 60; //warning 60 seconds
    var idle = 10; //warning when idle 10 seconds
    var urluser = <?php echo "'".Yii::app()->createUrl('site/lock', array('id'=>Yii::app()->user->id))."'"; ?>;

    var idlecountdown = countdown;
    var idletime = idle;
    var show = true;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second



    function timer(){

      count = count-1; idletime = idletime-1;
      if (count <= 0 ){ 
        clearInterval(counter);
        // counter ended, go to the lockscreen
        window.location.href = urluser;
        return;
      }
      if (count <= countdown || idletime <= 0){
        count = count<=countdown?count:countdown;
        // show warning
        if(show){
            document.getElementById('tombolmodal').click();
            show = false;
        }
        document.getElementById('sisadetik').innerHTML = count;
      }
      window.onmousemove = function(){ idletime=idle };
      window.onclick = function(){ idletime=idle };
      window.onmousedown = function(){ idletime=idle };
      window.onscroll = function(){ idletime=idle };
      window.onkeypress = function(){ idletime=idle };

      // when button stay signin cliked
      document.getElementById('staysignin').onclick = function() {
          // access properties using this keyword
          if ( this.click ) {
              count = <?php echo Yii::app()->session->getTimeout(); ?>;
              show = true;
              idletime = idle;
          }
      };
      document.getElementById('forcelogout').onclick = function() {
          // access properties using this keyword
          if ( this.click ) {
              window.location.href = urluser;
              return;
          }
      };
  }
</script>

<!-- design of modal -->
<button id='tombolmodal' style="display:none" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Large Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content panel-danger">
            <div class="modal-header panel-heading" style="border-radius: inherit;">
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ATTENTION!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <h3 class="text-danger">
                    It seems you are in inactive
                </h3>
                <p>
                    <b><span id="sisadetik"></span> seconds</b> left to logout your account
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            <!-- From this line, I Used YiiBooster Extension -->
            <?php $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButton',
                array(
                    'buttonType' => 'ajaxSubmit',
                    'context' => 'primary',
                    'label' => 'Keep Sign In',
                    'url' => CController::createUrl('site/keepalive'), 
                    'ajaxOptions' => array(
                        'type' => 'GET',
                    ),
                    'htmlOptions' => array(
                        "data-dismiss"=>"modal",
                        'id'=>'staysignin',
                    )
                )
            );
            ?>
            <?php $this->widget('booster.widgets.TbButton',
                array(
                    'context' => 'default',
                    'label' => 'Logout',
                    'htmlOptions' => array(
                        "data-dismiss"=>"modal",
                        "id"=>"forcelogout"
                    )
                )
            );
            ?>
            <!-- End of YiiBooster Extension -->
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my SiteController:

```
public function actionKeepalive()
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
        Yii::app()->session->open(); 
    }
}

public function actionLock($id)
{
    $user = User::model()->findByPk($id);
    Yii::app()->user->logout();
    $this->render('lock', array( //refers to lockscreen page
        'user'=>$user,
    ));
}
```

And **don't forget** to write the code from my question above.

That code worked very well in my website.

---

### This code is still have a weakness. When you log in with same account in different browser, they are not related to each other. they are independent. So, if the session in first browser has expired, the session in other browser may not expired yet or even has already expired earlier.

You can also see the implementation in Yii2 from this link: http://www.hafidmukhlasin.com/2014/10/01/yii2-create-lock-screen-web-application-with-javascript/

Thanks. Correct me if I wrong